# Minutes interval between two times past midnight in php

Tags: php, datetime, intervals

Users are allowed to pick a time for delivery up until the closing time of the store which can be 1am.

The list should should show all times up to 1am even if it is after midnight.

example 1: User arrives at `18:00` they see `18:00, 18:30, 19:00 and so on up until 00:30, 01:00`

example 2: user arrives at `00:10` should see

```
00:30, 01:00 not
01:00, 01:30, 02:00, 02:30 etc because after midnight has become a has become a new day/date.
```

I am getting 30 minute time intervals between two times, it is fine as long as both times are in the same day e.g. `17:00 and 23:00`. If the end time is past midnight I am not able to get the intervals so `17:00 to 01:00` doesn't give any intervals.

I understand 01:00 is another day but not quite sure how to fix it using a dynamic date. I keep thinking `current day +1` will be fine unless it is after mindight then it will be an extra day if that makes sense.

Here's my code:

```
$timestamp = time() + 60*60;
$earliest = date("h:i ",$timestamp);
$period = new DatePeriod(
new DateTime($earliest),
new DateInterval('PT30M'),
new DateTime('01:00')
);
foreach ($period as $date) {
echo '<option value="">'.$date->format("H:i").'</option>';
}
```

Because 24:00 works as 00:00 I tried 25:00 but that didn't work. Any help appreciated!

UPDATE: following the answer below coverted to dynamic date, if I use date like:

```
$start = date('Y-m-d H:i');
$startdate = date('Y-m-d');
$end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($startdate . ' +1 day'))." 01:00"; 
$period = new DatePeriod(
DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i','2020-04-03 17:00'),
new DateInterval('PT30M'),
DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i','2020-04-04 01:00')
      );
```

After midnight it's another day added on which is problematic.

Comment: Where does the interval end value come from? Is it dynamic? How do you define "after midnight", where is the cutoff? Technically, the entire tomorrow is "after midnight".

Comment: End value is set to 01:00 the next day everyday it's a constant.

Comment: What is the earliest available time? Seems like you should define it if you don't want to create a period from 01:30 today until 01:00 tomorrow if we're at 01:01 currently.

Comment: Or maybe I'm overengineering. If this program can be run only during working hours and is based on current time, then that wouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You also have to mention exact dates and not just time as `01:00`. Because this way, it assumes the current date and hence you really can't have a time period between `17:00` and `01:00` on the same day. Below is how you would do it:

```
<?php

$period = new DatePeriod(
                        DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i','2020-04-03 17:00'),
                        new DateInterval('PT30M'),
                        DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i','2020-04-04 01:00')
          );



foreach ($period as $date) {
    echo $date->format("H:i"),PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/5sj9Z

**Update:**

Since you have only times and not dates, you create DateTime objects, compare them, add 1 day to end time if it's smaller and then loop over the intervals using [`DatePeriod`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php)

```
<?php

$times = [
        ['18:00','01:00'],
        ['17:00','23:00'],
        ['00:10','01:00']
    ];

foreach($times as $time){
    $start_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i',$time[0]);
    $end_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i',$time[1]);
    if($end_time < $start_time){
        $end_time->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    }
    $period = new DatePeriod(
                        $start_time,
                        new DateInterval('PT30M'),
                        $end_time
              );


    echo $start_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),' ',$end_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($period as $date) {
        echo $date->format("H:i"),PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/Ldpst

Comment: Thanks for this, the usecase is on a daily basis so the dates are dynamic. The problem I am having with this approach is after 00:00 the dynamic next day goes to the following day, does that make sense?

Comment: @AbuNooh I didn't get it. Don't you have both start and end dates with you already?

Comment: I only have times no dates, so they;ll have to be dynamic. I have updated the question.

Comment: @AbuNooh Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can lose the whole timestamp calculation and have it all handled by `DateTime`:

```php
// here we get the next round delivery time
$nextAvailableHalfHour = getNextHalfHourMark();
$todayMidnight = new DateTime('today'); // this creates today with time 00:00:00
$todayOneOclock = new DateTime('today 01:00'); // this creates today with time 01:00:00
// this condition says if we're now between midnight and 1 o'clock, use today
// otherwise use tomorrow
$endDate = $nextAvailableHalfHour >= $todayMidnight && $nextAvailableHalfHour <= $todayOneOclock
    ? $todayOneOclock
    : new DateTime('tomorrow 01:00'); // create specific time tomorrow
$period = new DatePeriod(
    $nextAvailableHalfHour,
    new DateInterval('PT30M'),
    $endDate
);

/**
 * Gets the next available time with round half hour (:00 or :30).
 */
function getNextHalfHourMark(): DateTime
{
    $now = new DateTime(); // create current date and time
    $currentMinutes = (int) $now->format('i');
    // if we are between :00 and :30
    if ($currentMinutes > 0 && $currentMinutes < 30) {
        // set to :30 minutes of current hour
        $now->setTime($now->format('H'), 30);
    // else if we are between :30 and :00
    } elseif ($currentMinutes > 30 && $currentMinutes <= 59) {
        // set to :00 minutes of next hour
        $now->setTime($now->format('H') + 1, 00);
    }

    return $now;
}
```

The `tomorrow` and `today` strings are enabled by [relative formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).

Comment: Thank you, what will happen at 00:01 will 01:00 be 59 minutes away or 1 day plus 23:59 minutes away?

Comment: One day, because it creates tomorrow.

Comment: I only have start time end time no dates so the dates will be dynamic, how can I achieve 59 minutes away with the given example and not an extra day? Thank you much appreciated

Comment: Your criteria on using these times is very unclear. Can you please edit the question to describe the desired behaviour; when should today be used and when tomorrow?

Comment: Thanks for your patience with this, I was finding it hard to explain. I have updated the question.

Comment: @AbuNooh I've edited my answer to account for the period between midnight and 1 o'clock of the current day.